# Equations in two lines

Tags: equations

I expect the following equation to appear in two lines, but it shows in one line. Can you help me solve the issue?

```
\begin{equation}
F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha }).(\int^{\frac{q}{\alpha }}_0{(q-\alpha N).f(N)dN})+\left[1-F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha })\right].(\int^{q(1+\beta .\xi)}_0{[q-(N-\beta \xi q)]f(N)dN}) \notag\\
=F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha }).q.(F(\frac{q}{\alpha })-\alpha \int^{\frac{q}{\alpha }}_0{Nf(N)dN})+\left[1-F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha })\right].q(1+\beta .\xi ).(F(q(1+\beta .\xi ))-\int^{q(1+\beta .\xi )}_0{Nf(N)dN}).\notag\\
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit to post code, which we can copy and compile. As you can see easily by using and compiling a new .tex file, your snippet misses important parts, hence useful information for us. Please EDIT and add to your question. Thanks

Comment: Equation does not support line breaks use `gather` or `align` instead. For the latter you can use `&` to mark alignment points.

Comment: If you want to have the equation number vertically centered you could also use a `split` environment inside your `equation` environment.

Comment: With sincerity, your LaTeX code should be rewritten from the beginning. There are so many anomalies. For the size of the round brackets, for the multiplication symbol.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Also thank you for your great advice!

Answer (score 4):

There is no enough place for display this equation in two lines.

In the following code, I repeat your equation in one line, then an attempt using the `multline*` environment from the **amsmath** package (the star suppress the equation number, so `\notag` can be removed).

This environment displays the first line aligned on left, the last line aligned on right, and the intermediate lines centered.

For changing the alignement of the intermediate lines, we can use `\shoveleft` and `\shoveright`.

I have removed most (unless the final) dots because these are unnecessary. And when necessary for a multiplication sign, use "\cdot" (center dot) instead. Suppressing these "." saves the horizontal space.

Also, the parenthesis around the integrals are unnecessary, so they are removed. For better displaying, I have used `\left(` and `\right)` for automatic sizing of the parentheses. Also, the optional package **mleftright** gives better spacing around the parenthesis.

In the third attempt, as "q+\beta\xi q" takes less space than "q(1+\beta\xi)", the latter is replaced by the former.

And with `\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}` I modify the left and right margin for the formulas (initially 10pt).

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha }).(\int^{\frac{q}{\alpha }}_0{(q-\alpha N).f(N)dN})+\left[1-F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha })\right].(\int^{q(1+\beta .\xi)}_0{[q-(N-\beta \xi q)]f(N)dN}) \notag\\
=F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha }).q.(F(\frac{q}{\alpha })-\alpha \int^{\frac{q}{\alpha }}_0{Nf(N)dN})+\left[1-F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha })\right].q(1+\beta .\xi ).(F(q(1+\beta .\xi ))-\int^{q(1+\beta .\xi )}_0{Nf(N)dN}).\notag\\
\end{equation}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

% removing ".". Most (unless the final) are unnecessary. And when necessary for a multiplication sign, use "\cdot" (center dot).
% suppressing these "." saves the space.
% also, the parenthesis around the integrals are unnecessary
\begin{multline*}
F\left(\frac{\beta\xi q}{1-\alpha}\right)\int^{\frac{q}{\alpha }}_0{(q-\alpha N)f(N)dN}\\
\shoveright{+\left[1-F\left(\frac{\beta\xi q}{1-\alpha }\right)\right]\int^{q(1+\beta\xi)}_0{\left[q-(N-\beta \xi q)\right]f(N)dN}}\\
\shoveleft{=F\left(\frac{\beta\xi q}{1-\alpha }\right)q\left(F\left(\frac{q}{\alpha }\right)-\alpha\int^{\frac{q}{\alpha}}_0{Nf(N)dN}\right)}\\
+\left[1-F(\frac{\beta\xi q}{1-\alpha})\right]q(1+\beta \xi)\left(F\left(q(1+\beta\xi)\right)-\int^{q(1+\beta\xi )}_0{Nf(N)dN}\right).  
\end{multline*}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

% q+\beta\xi q takes less space than q(1+\beta\xi), so the latter is replaced by the former
\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt} % left and right margin for the formulas (initially 10pt)
\begin{multline*}
F\left(\frac{\beta\xi q}{1-\alpha}\right)\int^{\frac{q}{\alpha }}_0{(q-\alpha N)f(N)dN}\\
\shoveright{+\left[1-F\left(\frac{\beta\xi q}{1-\alpha }\right)\right]\int^{q+\beta\xi q}_0{\left[q-(N-\beta \xi q)\right]f(N)dN}}\\
\shoveleft{=F\left(\frac{\beta\xi q}{1-\alpha }\right)q\left(F\left(\frac{q}{\alpha }\right)-\alpha\int^{\frac{q}{\alpha}}_0{Nf(N)dN}\right)}\\
+\left[1-F(\frac{\beta\xi q}{1-\alpha})\right]q(1+\beta \xi)\left(F\left(q+\beta\xi q\right)-\int^{q+\beta\xi q}_0{Nf(N)dN}\right). 
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

(margin are displayed in red)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

You could to use the package `breqn` with the enviroment `dmath`, to split  automatically two equations.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha }).(\int^{\frac{q}{\alpha }}_0{(q-\alpha N).f(N)dN})+\left[1-F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha })\right].(\int^{q(1+\beta .\xi)}_0{[q-(N-\beta \xi q)]f(N)dN}) \notag\\
=F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha }).q.(F(\frac{q}{\alpha })-\alpha \int^{\frac{q}{\alpha }}_0{Nf(N)dN})+\left[1-F(\frac{\beta .\xi .q}{1-\alpha })\right].q(1+\beta .\xi ).(F(q(1+\beta .\xi ))-\int^{q(1+\beta .\xi )}_0{Nf(N)dN}).\notag\\
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very helpful.